# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

Tags: jsp, maven, taglib

So keep getting an jsp tag error (i think) or something related to pom.xml. I am not sure what I am doing wrong? Usually if i restart and clean it works fine. Any help? My collegue changed something on pom.xml after that this error keeps happening but i can't figure out what it is (he is currently on leave) and everything seems fine. The error shows up only where the tag files are. Here is the error and pom.xml

```
An error occurred at line: 12 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/main.jsp
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.mainbody_tag cannot be resolved to a type
9:  </head>
10:   <body ontouchstart="" onmouseover="">
11:     <tags:globalheader></tags:globalheader>
12:     <tags:mainbody></tags:mainbody>
13:     <tags:footer js="main"></tags:footer>
14:   </body>
15: 


An error occurred at line: 12 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/main.jsp
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.mainbody_tag cannot be resolved to a type
9:  </head>
10:   <body ontouchstart="" onmouseover="">
11:     <tags:globalheader></tags:globalheader>
12:     <tags:mainbody></tags:mainbody>
13:     <tags:footer js="main"></tags:footer>
14:   </body>
15: 


An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/main.jsp
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.footer_tag cannot be resolved to a type
10:   <body ontouchstart="" onmouseover="">
11:     <tags:globalheader></tags:globalheader>
12:     <tags:mainbody></tags:mainbody>
13:     <tags:footer js="main"></tags:footer>
14:   </body>
15: 
16: </html>


An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/views/main.jsp
org.apache.jsp.tag.web.footer_tag cannot be resolved to a type
10:   <body ontouchstart="" onmouseover="">
11:     <tags:globalheader></tags:globalheader>
12:     <tags:mainbody></tags:mainbody>
13:     <tags:footer js="main"></tags:footer>
14:   </body>
15: 
16: </html>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:95)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:457)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:352)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:339)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:594)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:344)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

                  pom.xml

<!--        spring dependecies, add more if you need other specific items from them-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-social-linkedin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.RC2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
<!--  <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also get this error alternates with the error mentioned above, which doesn't make sense.

```
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.main_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:168)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.main_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:132)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:162)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:391)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:209)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:266)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1225)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1012)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:931)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:822)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:807)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

You had omitted importing some Tag library being used by your tag, so it wouldn't compile.

Comment: sorry, which tag lib are you talking about? i have imported taglibs in maven?